# Background image under all page elements

Tags: html, css

I'm really new to coding and I am having some trouble.

I want to put a background image under all of my page elements that fits the entire screen. But when I try to do so the white coloring that is apart of all of the p's and h's that I've added overlap the image making the page look funky. Only part of the page gets the background image.

Here's the code I added to the css file.

```
html {
  background: url('imgurl') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
}
```

The html and css files are undoubtedly linked. Also, I used imgurl in my example code, but the actual code links to the right url.

Comment: All standard HTML elements are transparent by default. If they have a white background you must have applied it. Just remove it and your image will show through.

Answer (score 1):

Can't tell without showing a fiddle.

My guess will be doing this so it removes the background on the elements you mentioned.

```
h1, h2, h3, p {
  background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one of the easiest ways to accomplish this is to use the following css

```
#backgroundImage {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: -1;
}
```

and here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/usrp7yom/